# Is it better to overload the method, or use varargs to pass 0 to 1 variables? Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, overloading, variadic-functions

I'm a QA Tester. My background is not the best in understanding some best practices in Java.

Here is the scenario. I have one method that is used by multiple Tests. I realized that I need to put in a parameter for only very few tests into the method.

```
public static void verifyActivity() {
        CustomViewMatchers.waitForElementToBeEnabled(withId(R.id.(...)), 5);
}
```

I put in a solution for this as a varargs, at the moment into the framework.

```
public static void verifyActivity(boolean... buttonDisplay) {
     if (buttonDisplay == null)
        CustomViewMatchers.waitForElementToBeEnabled(withId(R.id.(...)), 5);
}
```

Which solution is best practice? Should I overload the method, or continue to use varargs.

Comment: [You aren't gonna need it (YAGNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Comment: Btw, if no arguments are supplied to `verifyActivity` in the second form, `buttonDisplay` is not null but an array of length 0.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're developing a library there is no point in having methods for potential future use. If the method without parameters is all you need at the moment, the additional varargs one should be removed.

Obvious drawback of the varargs method is the additional null check for the parameter and of course keeping unused code around increases maintenance cost. So if there's a chance to get rid of one of the methods it should be used.

As the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) point out:

> As an API designer, you should use them sparingly, only when the benefit is truly compelling. Generally speaking, you should not overload a varargs method, or it will be difficult for programmers to figure out which overloading gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Using varargs you can use the method with more than one parameter so i suggest to use overload. So something like this:

```
public static void verifyActivity() {
        verifyActivity(false);
}

public static void verifyActivity(boolean buttonDisplay) {
        if(buttonDisplay){
            CustomViewMatchers.waitForElementToBeEnabled(withId(R.id.(...)), 5);
        }
// do something
}
```